# Notify users using SqlDependency

Tags: c#, winforms, sqldependency

I'm trying to notify multiple application users connected to the same *SQLServer* that change happened on certain data base table. I decided to use *SQLDependency* class because it seemed like the best way to do so, but I can't get it to work. Your help is very much appreciated.

First of all I created *SqlWatcher* class to simplify the usage (credits go to [this blog)](http://jgowdy.blogspot.com/2010/01/sqldependency-query-notification-with.html):

```
public class SqlWatcher : IDisposable
{
    public delegate void SqlWatcherEventHandler(DataSet Result);
    public event SqlWatcherEventHandler OnChange;

    private string ConnectionString;
    private SqlConnection Connection;
    private SqlCommand Command;
    private SqlDataAdapter Adapter;
    private DataSet Result;

    public SqlWatcher(string ConnectionString, SqlCommand Command)
    {
        this.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
        SqlDependency.Start(this.ConnectionString);
        this.Connection = new SqlConnection(this.ConnectionString);
        this.Connection.Open();
        this.Command = Command;
        this.Command.Connection = this.Connection;
        Adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(this.Command);
    }

    public void ChangeEventWrapper(object state)
    {
        DataSet Result = (DataSet)state;
        OnChange(Result);
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Stop();
    }
    private void RegisterForChanges()
    {
        //Remove old dependency object
        this.Command.Notification = null;
        //Create new dependency object
        SqlDependency dep = new SqlDependency(this.Command);
        dep.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(Handle_OnChange);
        //Save data
        Result = new DataSet();
        Adapter.Fill(Result);
        OnChange(Result);
    }
    public void Start()
    {
        RegisterForChanges();
    }
    public void Stop()
    {
        SqlDependency.Stop(this.ConnectionString);
    }

    private void Handle_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDependency dep = (SqlDependency)sender;
        dep.OnChange -= Handle_OnChange;

        RegisterForChanges();
    }

    public DataSet DataSet
    {
        get { return Result; }
    }
}
```

From the main form user can add an item to the targeted *SqlDependency* command table and when that happens I want new form to pop-up with news. This is what my main form looks like:

```
public partial class MainForm: Form
{
    private string connectionString = @"data source = .\sqlexpress; initial catalog = Sample1; integrated security = true";
    private static SqlWatcher SqlQueueWatcher;

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeSqlDependency();
    }

    private void InitializeSqlDependency()
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID, Text FROM dbo.Notifications");
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        //Setup the SQLWatcher
        SqlQueueWatcher = new SqlWatcher(connectionString, cmd);
        SqlQueueWatcher.OnChange += new SqlWatcher.SqlWatcherEventHandler(QueueSQLWatcher_OnChange);
        SqlQueueWatcher.Start();
    }

    private static void QueueSQLWatcher_OnChange(DataSet Result)
    {
        NotificationForm notificationForm = new NotificationForm(Result);
        notificationForm.Show();
    }
    private void MainForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlQueueWatcher.Dispose();
    }
```

I expected this to work the way that when any user adds data to the *Notifications* data base other users get notified via *NotificationForm*. Could anyone tell me what am I doing wrong? I've been trying to figure it out myself for 2 days now.

*Thanks in advance!*

**P.S. If you have better idea on doing the same notification concept, feel free to express yourself.**

Comment: May be able to drill down to help you if you tell us what debugging is showing you, and where to look. Are any of the events firing?  Or are the events just not being seen in the hanlders?

Comment: @user1522548 QueueSQLWatcher_OnChange event is never fired and that's what's bothering me. It's like SqlDependency is not even watching for changes under command select statement.

Comment: Did you see this from MSFT? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aewzkxxh.aspx